# Mysql select where and order by

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax

i got a point system that are like people can upgrade to [PRO1] user. everyones rights(pro1,pro2,user) are stored in my mysql users table. But i want to make a little feed, that shows the latest one that upgraded to [PRO1]. the upgrade code:

```
 $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-50) WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and points > 50";
mysql_query($insert);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{

    // other codes

  $insert =  "UPDATE users SET rights=' [PRO1]' WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
    mysql_query($insert); 
header('location: succesupgrade.php');
}else{
    echo "You don't have enough points";
}


?>
```

the upgrade code works fine(just incase i need to add a time/date. and tha code for where i want the"'username' wast the last to upgrade to [PRO1]" is in this code:

```
    <?php
require("dbc.php");  
$query = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE rights='[PRO1]' order by right DESC limit 1") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "{$array['username']}<br>";
}
?>was the last to upgrade to:
<?php
require("dbc.php");  
$query = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE rights='[PRO1]' order by rights DESC limit 1") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "{$array['rights']}<br>";
}
?>
```

But that code gives me this error:`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC limit 1' at line 1`

Comment: New applications should not be using the creaky, accident-prone `mysql_query` interface. You're not [escaping SQL data](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and probably have several severe SQL injection bugs because of this.

Answer (score 1):

`order by right` must be `order by rights` in the first query of the second code block.

Comment: You wrote `right` without last `s` in the first query of the second code block!!!

Answer (score 1):

That query is going to do nothing to tell you who the last user to upgrade to `rights='[PRO1]'`.  That is just a string field.  You would need some sort of datetime/timestamp field that is updated when the users rights change, by which you can make the sort.

You also don't need to do 2 queries.  You have two queries doing the exact same thing.

Just do:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE rights='[PRO1]' ORDER BY update_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Where `update_timestamp` would be the field that is updated when the rights change.

Comment: yea, that was just what it hought.. but how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `right` is a used keyword, you need a back stroke to solve this :;

Like :

```
select * from `users` WHERE rights='[PRO1]' order by `rights` DESC limit 1
```

Comment: hm... when i replaced that code nothing happen. onyy the text(Was the newest one to upgrde to:" displayed

Comment: i'm goign to have the code like: $query = mysql_query("select * from `users` WHERE rights='[PRO1]' order by `rights` DESC limit 1") ? beacuse nothing is steel displaying. just the text